# How to compile Packages in java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to java , how do I compile packages in Intelij

This is my directory

[image]

It is running perfectly in Main.java

To compile , I first ran

javac people/People.java

Then I compile javac Main.java, it returns Main.java:8: error: package com.amigoscode.people does not exist

Main.java

```
package com.amigoscode;

// Press Shift twice to open the Search Everywhere dialog and type `show whitespaces`,
// then press Enter. You can now see whitespace characters in your code.


import java.util.Scanner;
import com.amigoscode.people.People;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        People p = new People();
        System.out.println(p.fullName());
    }

}
```

People.java

```
package com.amigoscode.people;

public class People {

    public String fname = "John";
    public String lname = "Doe";
    public int age = 24;


    public String fullName() {
        String fullName = fname + " " + lname;
        return fullName;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, navigate to the `src` directory using terminal. Then execute the command below to compile the `People.java`.

```
javac com/amigoscode/people/People.java
```

Now, to compile the `Main.java` execute the command below.

```
javac com/amigoscode/Main.java
```

This should work fine.

Comment: As @chameerar said It will work even if you skip the separate compilation of People class, you can directly do that by compiling the Main.java. Just you need to go to the path ..\untitled\src> javac Main.java
that's it.